# Use tag in svg's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm pretty new to SVG. I have set of icons created using SVG. I'm trying to use `<use>` tag to render a particular part of SVG. But everything goes in vain. Not able to figure out what's the mistake i'm doing. Here is the code which i tried and also refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santhoshkumar14/2vvc1arL/). You can see that overall svg is rendered, But trying to render particular part of the SVG failed. Any help will be appreciated

```
  <svg width="303px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 303 30" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <g id="Pivot" transform="translate(253.232000, 6.247500)">
      <path d="M0.833,15.4105 L0.833,11.662 L3.7485,11.662 L3.7485,11.2455 L0.833,11.2455 L0.833,7.9135 L3.7485,7.9135 L3.7485,7.497 L0.833,7.497 L0.833,4.5815 L0,4.5815 L0,16.2435 L0.833,16.2435 L0.833,15.827 L3.7485,15.827 L3.7485,15.4105 L0.833,15.4105 Z M18.8036328,16.2435 L4.5815,16.2435 L4.5815,15.6124537 L8.7465,15.6124537 L8.7465,12.7095463 L4.5815,12.7095463 L4.5815,12.0785 L8.7465,12.0785 L8.7465,8.12804634 L4.5815,8.12804634 L4.5815,7.497 L8.7465,7.497 L8.7465,4.5815 L3.7485,4.5815 L3.7485,4.4408921e-16 L19.5755,4.4408921e-16 L19.5755,4.5815 L17.3516962,4.5815 L14.5775,4.5815 L14.5775,7.497 L18.7425,7.497 L18.7425,4.5815 L19.5755,4.5815 L19.5755,16.2435 L18.8036328,16.2435 Z M18.7425,15.6124537 L14.5775,15.6124537 L14.5775,12.7095463 L18.7425,12.7095463 L18.7425,15.6124537 Z M18.7425,12.0785 L14.5775,12.0785 L14.5775,8.12804634 L18.7425,8.12804634 L18.7425,12.0785 Z M13.7445,4.5815 L9.5795,4.5815 L9.5795,7.497 L13.7445,7.497 L13.7445,4.5815 Z M13.7445,8.12804634 L9.5795,8.12804634 L9.5795,12.0785 L13.7445,12.0785 L13.7445,8.12804634 Z M13.7445,12.7095463 L9.5795,12.7095463 L9.5795,15.6124537 L13.7445,15.6124537 L13.7445,12.7095463 Z M3.7485,4.5815 L4.5815,4.5815 L4.5815,16.2435 L3.7485,16.2435 L3.7485,4.5815 Z M0,3.7485 L3.7485,3.7485 L3.7485,4.165 L0,4.165 L0,3.7485 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#AAAAAA"></path>
      <rect id="Rectangle-324" fill="#FAC10C" x="0" y="3.7485" width="4.5815" height="12.495"></rect>
      <rect id="Rectangle-324-Copy" fill="#FAC10C" transform="translate(11.733102, 2.290750) rotate(90.000000) translate(-11.733102, -2.290750) " x="9.44235203" y="-5.73533321" width="4.5815" height="16.0521664"></rect>
   </g>
   <g id="Filter" transform="translate(232.407000, 6.247500)">
      <rect id="Rectangle-108" fill="#3BA3F8" x="4.73505679e-14" y="0" width="12.9115" height="1.2495"></rect>
      <rect id="Rectangle-109" fill="#3BA3F8" x="4.73505679e-14" y="2.499" width="12.9115" height="1.2495"></rect>
      <path d="M6.33160096,10.829 L6.45575,10.9678333 L6.57989904,10.829 L6.33160096,10.829 Z M4.8418125,9.163 L4.73505679e-14,3.7485 L12.9115,3.7485 L8.0696875,9.163 L4.8418125,9.163 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#8EC9FB"></path>
      <path d="M4.5815,9.163 L7.9135,9.163 L7.9135,18.326 L4.74601819,14.5516554 L4.5815,9.163 Z" id="Rectangle-111" fill="#8EC9FB"></path>
   </g>
   <g id="Sort" transform="translate(206.167500, 1.666000)">
      <rect id="Rectangle-120" fill="#E2A364" x="10.829" y="4.165" width="2.0825" height="17.9095"></rect>
      <path d="M15.5828281,14.5775 L17.1391718,15.7502891 L12.3853437,22.0588321 L10.829,20.886043 L15.5828281,14.5775 Z" id="Rectangle-121" fill="#E2A364"></path>
      <text id="A" font-family="SFUIDisplay-Semibold, SF UI Display" font-size="11.902719" font-weight="500" letter-spacing="-0.107586779" fill="#19AF5C">
         <tspan x="0.4165" y="11">A</tspan>
      </text>
      <text id="Z" font-family="SFUIDisplay-Semibold, SF UI Display" font-size="11.902719" font-weight="500" letter-spacing="-0.107586779" fill="#19AF5C">
         <tspan x="0.4165" y="22.662">Z</tspan>
      </text>
   </g>
</svg>
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="Pivot"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is it a typo or are you trying to reference an element from another SVG?

Comment: I'm trying to refer @Robert. Is there is any possibilities of doing so

Answer (score 2):

You want to know why the "Pivot" element is not showing up in your second SVG?  Is that right?

The reason is because you are not referencing it correctly.  You should have written:

```
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="#Pivot"></use>
</svg>
```

Note the missing hash ("#") symbol.

Comment: Good one anyways that was done by mistake. See my updated [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/santhoshkumar14/2vvc1arL/1/). Icon is not visible by setting height and width to svg. Why it's happening

Comment: In the original SVG, the "Pivot" element is at the right edge of a 303px wide SVG. Your new SVG is only 30px wide. So your Pivot element is now way off the right hand side of your SVG. You would need to move it back into the visible area by changing the X position of the <use>. Eg. `<use x="-250" ...>`